# How to turn off AssertionError in cypress when I use if else

Tags: cypress

I have a problem with if in cypress test, when the element is not visible I receive: "AssertionError:
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [type="alertdialog"], but never found it."
but I would like to receive cy.log("test") when the element is not visible. There is any possibility to do that?

````
            if ($dis.is(':visible')) {
                cy.get('[button="reject"]').click()
            } else {
                cy.log("test")
            }
        })```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work if the the problem was **visibility**, but it's probably **existence**.

Try

```js
if ($dis.length > 0) {
  cy.get('[button="reject"]').click()
} else {
  cy.log("test")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. Example based on Cypress docs...

```
cy.get('body').then($body => {
    const dis = $body.find('.some_class')
    if (dis.length) {
        cy.get('[button="reject"]').click()
    } else {
        cy.log("test")
    }
})
```